# Is Regex Sufficient, or Do I need to check Encoding?

Tags: java, regex, character-encoding

I have a requirement to ensure that email addresses contain standard U.S. English characters.  Without debating what that means and whether it is advisable, I am wondering if a regex alone is enough to satisfy that requirement, or do I also need to check the character set?

Are there any circumstances in which a UTF-8 character could be pass a regex, but not be in the Latin character set that is used in the regex?

This is some code I am using, and it appears to me that the regex is sufficient, but I wanted a 2nd opinion.

```
package misc;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class ValidateCharacterSet {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String czech = "Český";
        String japanese = "日本語";
        String spanish = "¡Qué magnifico es java!";
        String english = "elephant_in-theRoom@yahoo.com";

        System.out.println("iso check: " + czech + ":" + isISO8859(czech));
        System.out.println("iso check: " + japanese + ":" + isISO8859(japanese));
        System.out.println("iso check: " + spanish + ":" + isISO8859(spanish));
        System.out.println("iso check: " + english + ":" + isISO8859(english));

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("regex match: " + czech + ":" + playWithMatches(czech));
        System.out.println("regex match: " + japanese + ":" + playWithMatches(japanese));
        System.out.println("regex match: " + spanish + ":" + playWithMatches(spanish));
        System.out.println("regex match: " + english + ":" + playWithMatches(english));
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if the string is null, or the original string (str) equals the string (encodedAsISO8859)
     * that was encoded ISO-8859-1.
     *
     * @param str String containing bytes for which to check the encoding.
     * @return True if the string is in ISO-8859-1 format.
     */
    private static boolean isISO8859(String str) {
        // a null string is compliant by definition.
        if (str == null) {
            return true;
        }

        try {
            byte[] iso88591Data = str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            String encodedAsISO8859 = new String(iso88591Data, "ISO-8859-1");
            if (str.equals(encodedAsISO8859)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean playWithMatches(String str) {
        return (str != null && str.matches("[A-Za-z0-9\\-_\\.@\\+]+"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up *character sets* and *character encoding.* Character sets are the set of characters permissible or available, while character encoding describes how you access the character set. The distinction is not apparent with character sets like ISO-8859-1, where there is a single standard encoding which is that passing in a number gets you the character associated with that number. It is more apparent when dealing with a character set like Unicode as there are multiple encodings for the one character set, namely [UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (Java uses UTF-16 in its Strings).

Once you've defined what your character set is, in this case "Standard U.S. English characters," a regex is sufficient to check if the characters in a given string contains only those characters in the character set. You don't need to, nor do you want to deal with lower-level encoding issues if it is not necessary. Case in point, your `isISO8859` method is technically not guaranteed to work. Both the `getBytes` method and `String` constructor you used are [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) as having unspecified behaviour when given characters/bytes are not valid as part of the specified character encoding.